# How to grep a still unknown specific word in a matched row

Tags: grep

I have a file made of some rows and the one I am interested in is like this one:

```
free energy    TOTEN  =       -96.86706464 eV
```

So with grep I can find the row I need and assign to a variable the value of the row with:

```
E=$(grep "free  energy" OUTCAR_$i)
```

Now, how do I do if want to assign to E a specific word present in the matched line obtained by using grep, the numeric value in this case? Please note that value I want to grep is the unknown I am looking, but it is always present at the same position in the row!

Thank you

Comment: Try GNU `sed`, `E=$(sed -n '/free energy/{s/.* \(-[0-9][0-9.]*\).*/\1/p}' "OUTCAR_$i")`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/D5wGch). With GNU grep: `E=$(grep -oP 'free energy.* \K-[0-9][0-9.]*' "OUTCAR_$i")`, or - if the first match is required - `E=$(grep -oP -m1 'free energy.* \K-[0-9][0-9.]*' "OUTCAR_$i")`

Comment: Are you limited to `grep` or can you use other available tools also? Can you write out your expected output? Does it include the minus sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `grep`, you may use a PCRE regex solution:

```
E=$(grep -oP 'free energy.* \K-?[0-9][0-9.]*' "OUTCAR_$i")
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/lZAakx)

With GNU `sed`, you may extract the negative value from a line:

```
E=$(sed -n '/free energy/{s/.* \(-\{0,1\}[0-9][0-9.]*\).*/\1/p}' "OUTCAR_$i")
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/l9QICB).

If the number of non-whtespace chunks is a fixed value extract the fifth field if the line contains `free energy`:

```
E=$(awk '$0 ~ /free energy/{print $5}' "OUTCAR_$i")
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/iqsB3d)